# Any way to get access to Java application's title bar (placement of additional buttons etc.)

Tags: java, desktop

Is there any way to customize Java application's title bar? I don't mean app name in title bar of course, but total customization, that can be seen in some modern non Java applications which utilize long years wasted space with three buttons in the corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated() and the JRootPane with RootPaneUI classes. You won't be able to change the system-provided title bar, but you might be able to tweak one of the Java custom UI's implementations.